# Wordpress - get the post count number of a taxonomy term and get the taxonomy term id in the loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to accomplish a nice portfolio listing by the help of the http://mixitup.io/ jquery plugin.

So I created a custom post type, 'portfolio' and in the archive-portfolio.php I created the filters by listing the taxonomy terms of 'portfolio'

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("portfolio_categories");
             $count = count($terms);
             if ( $count > 0 ){
                 echo '<ul class="list-group">';
                 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                   echo '<li class="list-group-item" data-filter="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '<span class="badge"> ' . $term->count . '</span></li>';

                 }
                 echo '</ul>';
             }  
             ?>
```

So in the first instance I need to get the post count of each term and replace it with what I used and didn't function: `$term->count`

After creating the filters I need to create the grid so I made a loop to get all the posts in the custom post 'portfolio'

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 99 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $post_number = 0; ?>
 <ul id="portfolio-grid">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
   <li class=""><?php echo the_title() ?> </li>         
<?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
```

Here I need to assign the category slug of the term in the empty class quotes of the li so that I can make the plugin work properly.

Any chance you can help me with that?